# Android MVP - Calling View method inside View implementation (Fragements or Activity)

Tags: android, mvp

I was implementing MVP in my new application, then I came across a problem. I needed to call a method of `View`, inside `View` (`Activity`) itself. It is by definition of MVP code separation, wrong thing to do.

**By definition:**

*The Presenter is in charge of the the orchestration between the Model and the View. It basically receive events from both and act consequently. The Presenter is the only component that knows others. It has a reference to the View and a another to the Model.* ([source](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-mvp-doing-it-right-dac9d5d72079))

In the same article it was mentioned that `View` does not reacts to user interactions, it passes control to `Presenter` to do the job. I have also read [this SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473696/android-mvp-dependency-rules) about dependency rules.

In my case, I am using custom `AppTheme`. `AppTheme` needs to be set before `setContent()` call, what I am doing is create a method in `View` interface called `setAppTheme()` which my `Activity` implements, and there is code to apply theme. Now the problem is, this is called within the app, which makes calling of a `View` method inside its implementation.

> To sum up, what my understanding of MVP either one of the following
>   should be true:
>
> - Do call `View` method inside `Activity`, because `setTheme()` wont work after `setContent()` and our `presenter.setView()` is in
>     `onResume()`, but will this satisfy MVP separation of M-V-P ?
> - Do not make interface method for `setAppTheme()`, instead create a private method in `Activity` which sets theme. This method will have
>     nothing to do with any layer of MVP. But question is, if project is
>     using MVP pattern, is this practice valid?

Here is my MVP:

```
public class AboutUsMVP
{

    public interface Model
    {


        String getFbLink();
        String getTwitterLink();
        String getEmailLink();
        String getCompanyLink();

    }

    public interface Presenter
    {
        void setView( View view );

        void fbButtonClicked();

        void twitterButtonClicked();

        void emailButtonClicked();

        void imageButtonClicked();

    }

    public interface View
    {

        void showFacebookPage();
        void showTwitterPage();
        void showEmailIntent();
        void showCompanyWebsite();
        void setAppTheme();
        void setCustomActionBar();

    }

}
```

Please do point out mistakes where I missed them.

> From what I know, same case can be argued in the light of
>   `setActionBar()` and `setOnClickListener()` methods, although these
>   may require their separate post, but they are more relevant here and
>   new post for either of them will be duplicate.

Please note that my **Activity implements View interface.**

**EDIT: *More explanation***

My View is actually Activity class. This is View of M**V**P, **not** Android API's `View` class. The thing is, there is a method `setAppTheme()` which only related to View of MVP, (`Activity` of Android). This call is not in the Contract (`AboutUsMVP.java`) which by Google convention should be `AboutUsContract.java`, this `setAppTheme()` is not in Contract, and it cant be, so does this violate MVP principle?

There is no possible alternative, one can say make an interface of `setAppTheme()`, if I do so, it will not work because:

`setAppTheme()` is called just after `super()` method, if not it is useless. And MVP's presenter starts working in `onResume`. If an interface is made, and `setAppTheme()` *is brought into MVP's jurisdiction*, it will have no effect.

Comment: Is your theme dynamic and based on user's interactions? Otherwise why not to set the theme directly in the Manifest? I'm quite new with MVP too but I think it's correct to call the Presenter to init the View (your `setView()`) in onCreate, then the Presenter calls `setAppTheme`. Just after `presenter.setView()` you can call `setContentView` as normal.

Comment: Yes, user can change theme while app is running, and it will be saved in consistent storage.

Comment: You can my repo related MVP from here https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sampleapp/module/fragmentsample

Comment: If you looking in kotlin then go here https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleAppKotlin

Comment: Will have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `View`s in an MVP are supposed to be *dumb*. This is: they don't contain any logic. Just receive the event generated by the user and **immediately** delegate its work to the presenter. The `View` can also inform the presenter that *some events*  have happened (the view has been created, the screen rotate, etc)

This can lead to some confusions. Who is responsible of calling some methods? As you said the `View` **has** to perform some actions like `setOnClickListener` but the presenter is responsible of handling the event. Just have this in mind:

> The `View` is just an **interface**. This means that you can use **anything** that implements that interface

Right now you're making a mobile app. But if you wanted to code a console or a desktop app, the presentation logic **doesn't change**. Anything that is specific to the "View technology" (android, desktop, etc) should be performed inside the code specific to that technology. This way your code will be loosely coupled to your tech stack

Comment: _Anything that is specific to the "View technology" (android, desktop, etc) should be performed inside the code specific to that technology._  


  My View is actually Activity class. This is View of M**V**P, **not** Android API's `View` class. The thing is, there is a method `setAppTheme()` which only related to View of MVP, (`Activity` of Android). This call is not in the Contract (`AboutUsMVP.java`) which by Google convention should be AboutUsContract.java`, this `setAppTheme()` is not in Contract, and it cant be, so does this violate MVP principle?
See EDIT: More explanation.

Comment: When I said *View* I was refering always to whatever UI you use. If your code is Android specific you should put it in your activity. If your code is just presentation logic put it in the presenter

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Pelocho answer is correct and you should mark it as the right one. But I would like to present my answer (that agrees with his) but from an alternative point-of-view. On for this different POV I would like to debate your on definition of presenter:

> The Presenter is in charge of the the orchestration between the Model
>   and the View

So the question I propose here is: "what is this model that the presenter interacts with?". And my answer to it is to look into the classic "note-taking" application and argue that the model is text and associated meta-data, usually stored in some DB that the presenter will read, parse and push to the view.

Nowhere in this "model" the application theme is relevant. Theme is purely a function of the view. Theme is only associated to the final on-screen looks of it. Just like the view is the one in charge of layouting the content on screen, or to know what font size to use.

And that means even if those layouting, size, colors can be changed from a user settings option, it still falls outside the responsibility of the presenter and the model, as they're only interested in the content.

**tl;dr:**

Just read the theme on the `Activity.onCreate` (before super.onCreate) directly from the SharedPreferences and do not involve the Presenter on it.

Comment: If that is your definition of "Presenter"... maybe you're using an MVC instead of an MVP. Because that's the definition of a `Controller`. The Presenter is in charge of the presentation logic.